# Extra new line on print Python

Tags: python, optimization

I have small fun function that prints rhombus with asterisks. It looks like this:

```
from time import sleep

while True:
    whitespaces_count = 0
    dots_count = 8
    for _ in range(0, 5):
        print("*"*(dots_count//2)+" "*whitespaces_count+"*"*(dots_count//2))
        whitespaces_count += 2
        dots_count -= 2
        sleep(0.15)
    whitespaces_count = 6
    dots_count = 2
    for _ in range(0, 4):
        print("*"*(dots_count//2)+" "*whitespaces_count+"*"*(dots_count//2))
        whitespaces_count -= 2
        dots_count += 2
        sleep(0.15)
    print("\n")
```

It works fine, but, after every `print` command, it prints additional blank line, so output looks like this:

```
********
***  ***
**    **
*      *

*      *
**    **
***  ***
********
```

But I want it looks like this:

```
********
***  ***
**    **
*      *
*      *
**    **
***  ***
********
```

---

What am I'm doing wrong?

Comment: All posts asking for debugging help should have a [mre], so I have to ask: Why do you use `sleep`? Is it important that the code is in a `while True` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't `print`, it's that your first loop runs one extra time printing no dots, all whitespace. Change it to loop over `range(4)` instead of `range(5)` and that extra line goes away.

---

Side-note: You should really take advantage of the loop itself to do the work of determining how many asterisks and spaces to `print`; you're using a `range` to decide how many loops to run, but it could do double duty, allowing this (minimally fixed code):

```
whitespaces_count = 0
dots_count = 8
for _ in range(4):
    print("*"*(dots_count//2)+" "*whitespaces_count+"*"*(dots_count//2))
    whitespaces_count += 2
    dots_count -= 2
    sleep(0.15)
```

to become:

```
for whitespaces_count in range(0, 8, 2):
    dots_count = 8 - whitespaces_count
    print("*"*(dots_count//2)+" "*whitespaces_count+"*"*(dots_count//2))
    sleep(0.15)
```

or letting the loop do even more work, pushing more work to built-ins that outperform hand-written code (and having `dots_count` refer to the number of dots on each side):

```
for whitespaces_count, dots_count in zip(range(0, 8, 2), range(4, 0, -1)):
    print("*"*dots_count + " "*whitespaces_count + "*"*dots_count)
    sleep(0.15)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `for _ in range(0, 5):`, you're looping once more than in your second loop. Try the following:

```
from time import sleep

while True:
    whitespaces_count = 0
    dots_count = 8
    for _ in range(0, 4):
        print("*"*(dots_count//2)+" "*whitespaces_count+"*"*(dots_count//2))
        whitespaces_count += 2
        dots_count -= 2
        sleep(0.15)
    whitespaces_count = 6
    dots_count = 2
    for _ in range(0, 4):
        print("*"*(dots_count//2)+" "*whitespaces_count+"*"*(dots_count//2))
        whitespaces_count -= 2
        dots_count += 2
        sleep(0.15)
    print("\n")
```